# using paste() in a for loop with glm

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, paste, glm

In the code below, df.pts is a dataframe.  I'd like to run about dozen glm models using different y variable (only two shown in the code).  I'm using a for loop with the paste() function, but I can't seem to get the paste() function to work properly.  What am I missing with paste()?

```
SPCA2 = df.pts[,3]
CLQU2 = df.pts[,4]

df.list = list(SPCA2, CLQU2)

for (i in df.list) {
    qp.mod = glm(paste(i,"~NDVI+ELEV"), family="quasipoisson", data=my.data)
    print(summary(gp.mod))
 }
```

Comment: Did you try `qp.mod = glm(as.formula(paste(i,"~NDVI+ELEV")), family="quasipoisson", data=my.data)`?

Comment: the problem might be with `data=my.data`; R will try to find the variables enunciated in the formula into this seemingly unexistent (?) `my.data`. If `NDVI` and `ELEV` are indeed in a dataframe named `my.data`, then the problem is elsewhere. But if they are just vectors not belonging to any dataframe, just omit the `data=my.data` argument.

Comment: An issue is that you are passing a vector of values (ie `df.pts[,3]`) to the `formula`. You want to pass the name of the variable here. So `df.list` should be a list of variable names not actual data. side note is that you have a typo in your summary statement.

Comment: Many thanks!  The main problem was that df.list was a list of vectors, and should have been a list of names.  That was corrected by using df.list = ("SPCA2", "CLQU2") instead of list().  However, it was also correctly pointed out that the dataframe, my.data, was not the correct dataframe.  Finally, while it worked without  it, the function as.formula() also worked.  Again, many thanks!

Comment: @JohnLowry; you should write this as an answer so it may help future searches (an accept it;))

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks! The main problem was that df.list was a list of vectors, and should have been a list of names.

I other words, to correct the problem...

```
df.list = ("SPCA2", "CLQU2")
```

instead of

```
df.list = list(SPCA2, CLQU2)
```

However, it was also correctly pointed out that the dataframe, my.data, was not the correct dataframe. Finally, while it worked without it, the function as.formula() also worked. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `as.formula` before `paste` to let R know you want to treat it as a formula instead of characters.

```
qp.mod = glm(as.formula(paste(i,"~NDVI+ELEV")), family="quasipoisson", data=my.data)
```