# How to paste row names in a for loop with R

Tags: r

I'm trying to paste row names in a for loop in R. This is so I can keep the id in the output for each loop for easier segmentation.

My for loop works well. It's just that my paste function does not.

UK_profileList is  data frame. The function `get_ga` below is from the RGA package.

My code is:

```
start.date <- "2015-01-01"
end.date <- format(Sys.Date(), format = "%Y-%m-%d")

for (i in 1:nrow(UK_profileList)) {

  allData <- get_ga(UK_profileList[i,], start.date, end.date, dimensions = "ga:month, ga:day, ga:minute", metrics = "ga:sessions")

  row.names(allData[i]) <- paste(UK_profileList[i,], sep="")

}
```

I get the error:

Error in

row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = "8131437") : 
  invalid 'row.names length

Please note, I am aware of this post here:[using paste() in a for loop with glm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553707/using-paste-in-a-for-loop-with-glm)

But it is specific to glm...

Comment: Does changing your paste function to `paste(UK_profileList[i,], collapse = "")` work?

Comment: Maybe `row.names(allData[i]) <- paste(as.character(UK_profileList[i,]), sep="")`

Comment: trying changing `row.names(allData[i])` to `row.names(allData[i,])`

Comment: Thanks @Andrelrms, but the error then changes to: Error in rownames<-(x, value) : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions

Comment: @GKyle I have another thought, why don't you create the names inside the loop, say `new.names[i] <- paste(UK_profileList[i,], sep="")` then after then after the loop you rename the row names `row.names(allData)<-new.names`. I will make an example and post it

Comment: Did you get any errors? could you show a small snippet of your data with `head(dput())`? Your data goes inside of the parentheses, so we can take a look

Comment: Thanks @erasmortg. I get an error: Error in row.names<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value = "8131437") : 
  invalid 'row.names length.

Snippet:

`structure(list(month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L`

Comment: Thanks @CactusWoman but I get the same error

Comment: @GKyle thank you for answering. Could you update with your data structures inside of the post? That way you are not restricted to the size limit of comments. A `head(dput())` of `UK_profileList` could be much more informative in terms of types and classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was talking about in the comment:

```
allData<-data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rexp(10))
new.names<-NULL
for(i in 1:10){
 new.names[i]<-paste(letters[i],i,sep="")
}

row.names(allData)<-new.names
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrelrms. I think this is getting close. I use

`id.names <- NULL

for (i in 1:nrow(UK_profileList)) {
  
  allData <- get_ga(UK_profileList[i,], start.date, end.date, dimensions = "ga:month, ga:day, ga:minute", metrics = "ga:sessions")
  id.names[i] <- paste(UK_profileList[i,],i, sep = "")
}`

But I get the same error. What is happening here, is that a character vector gets built containing each unique id used. What we need is something that contains the id which pertains to each row in allData. Thus, will be the same length and will paste in seamlessly. Thanks!